# Increase Speed of Nested For Loops While Changing Value of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to increase the speed of the nested for loops.

VARIABLES:

'dataframe' - The dataframe I am attempting to modify in the second for loop. It consists of a multitude of training sessions for the same people. This is the attendance document that is changed if a match exists in the reporting dataframe.

'dictNewNames' - This is a dictionary of session title names. The key is the longer session title name and the value is a stripped session title name. For example {'Week 1: Training': 'Training'} etc. The key is equal to the 'Session Title' column in each row but the value is used for searching a substring in the second for loop.

'reporting' - A dataframe that includes information regarding session titles and attendance participation. The reporting dataframe is already filtered so everyone in the 'reporting' dataframe should get credit in 'dataframe'. The only caveat is that the 'search' name is nested within the pathway title.

```
dataframe = {
'Session Title': ['Organization Week 1: Train', 'Organization Week 2: Train', 'Organization Week 3: Train'],
'Attendee Email': ['name@gmail.com', 'name2@gmail.com', 'name3@gmail.com'],
'Completed': ['No', 'No', 'No'],
'Date Completed': ['','','']}

dictNewNames = { 'Organization Week 1: Train': 'Train', ' Organization Week 2: Train': 'Train', 'Organization Week 3: Train': 'Train' }
```

### Title formatting is not incorrect (i.e. ':' vs '-' as seen in pathway title below). The data is completely all over the place in terms of format.

```
reporting = {
'Pathway Title': ['Training 1 - Train', 'Training 2: Train', 'Training 3 - Train'],
'Email': ['name@gmail.com', 'name2@gmail.com', 'name3@gmail.com'],
'Date Completed': ['xx/yy/xx', 'yy/xx/zz', 'zz/xx/yy']}

expectedOuput = {
'Session Title': ['Organization Week 1: Train', 'Organization Week 2: Train', 'Organization Week 3: Train'],
'Attendee Email': ['name@gmail.com', 'name2@gmail.com', 'name3@gmail.com'],
'Completed': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
'Date Completed': ['xx/yy/xx', 'yy/xx/zz', 'zz/xx/yy']}
```

My code:

```
def giveCredit(dataframe, dictNewNames, reporting):

    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():


        temp = row['Session Title']
        searchName = dictNewNames[temp]

        attendeeEmail = row['Attendee: Email']


        for index1, row1 in reporting.iterrows():

            pathwayTitle = row1['Pathway Title']
            Email = row1['Organization Email']
            dateCompleted = row1['Date Completed']

            if attendeeEmail == Email and searchName in pathwayTitle:
                dataframe.at[index, 'Completed'] = 'Yes'
                dataframe.at[index, 'Date Completed'] = dateCompleted
                break

    return dataframe
```

Comment: Please update your post with a Minimal Reproducible Example. We need some data as plain text of `dataframe`, `reporting` and `dictNewNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern looks like `merge`:

```
for loop1 on first dataframe:
   for loop2 on second dataframe:
       if conditions match between both dataframes:
```

So:

```
# Create a common key Name based on dictNewNames
pat = fr"({'|'.join(dictNewNames.values())})"
name1 = dataframe['Session Title'].map(dictNewNames)
name2 = reporting['Pathway Title'].str.extract(pat)

# Merge dataframes based on this key and email
out = pd.merge(dataframe.assign(Name=name1),
               reporting.assign(Name=name2),
               left_on=['Name', 'Attendee Email'],
               right_on=['Name', 'Email'],
               how='left', suffixes=(None, '_'))

# Update the dataframe
out['Date Completed'] = out.pop('Date Completed_')
out['Completed'] = np.where(out['Date Completed'].notna(), 'Yes', 'No')
out = out[dataframe.columns]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Session Title   Attendee Email Completed Date Completed
0  Week 1: Train 1   name@gmail.com       Yes       xx/yy/xx
1  Week 2: Train 2  name2@gmail.com       Yes       yy/xx/zz
2  Week 3: Train 3  name3@gmail.com       Yes       zz/xx/yy
```

Comment: I deliberately broke down my code to be easier to understand and avoided the one-liner

Comment: @achi00. I missed Email column. I fixed my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: It looks right for my initial question. Unfortunately, there are overlaps in the session titles and the only distinguishing factor is a number. I need to look for the first numeric character in session title for each row, and check as third criteria when finding a match in the reporting dataframe 'Pathway Title' Column. There's not always a number in the 'Pathway Title' Column that matches in the reporting dataframe. But it should be checked first to initially refine the search. If not, merge where only email and session title match (without extra numeric key).. My solution is updated to fix.

Comment: Any further help would be much appreciated. Let me know if there is any confusion!

Comment: After `merge`, you can use `query` or `loc` to filter out your dataframe and remove some dups. Maybe update your example with such case and display the expected output could help.

Comment: There is no longer duplicates. But the problem is when I am attempting to merge the dataframe I am merging on the email and then the 'Pathway Title'. Unfortunately, there are trainings with the same names but in different weeks. Because of this it's giving the correct credit to the individuals but the data of completion is ambiguous since the match can find multiple rows in the reporting dataframe with the vague session title, and email. I need to include the first number in the row to distinguish what week in  the reporting dataframe and therefor which date is copied into the dataframe.

Comment: Please update your post and give the expected output.

Comment: You should be all set now. I just wanted to add that the format within column 'Pathway Title' is not incorrect. The format of the sessions names is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

### This workaround cut my execution time from 460 seconds to under 10.

```py
def giveCredit(dataframe, dictNewNames, reporting):

    reporting['Date Completed'] = pd.to_datetime(reporting['Date Completed'])

    for index1, row in dataframe.iterrows():

        temp = row['Session Title']
        numberList = re.findall('[0-9]+', temp)
        finalNumber = str(numberList[0])


        searchName = dictNewNames[temp]
        attendeeEmail = row['Attendee: Email']

        row = reporting.loc[(reporting['Pathway Title'].str.contains(searchName, case=False)) & (reporting['Organization Email'] == attendeeEmail)]

        if len(row.index) != 0:
            new_row = row.loc[(reporting['Pathway Title'].str.contains(finalNumber, case=False))]

            if len(new_row.index) != 0:
                dataframe = modifyFrame(dataframe, new_row, index1)
            else:
                dataframe= modifyFrame(dataframe, row, index1)

    dataframe = dataframe.sort_values(["Completed", "Attendee"], ascending=[False, True])

    return dataframe




def modifyFrame(frame, row, index1):

    dateCompleted = row['Date Completed']
    dateCompleted = dateCompleted.to_string(buf=None, header=False, index=False, length=False, name=False, max_rows=None).strip()
    dataframe.at[index1, 'Completed'] = 'Yes'
    dataframe.at[index1, 'Date Completed'] = dateCompleted

    return dataframe
```